# Временной цикл в С++

Tags: c++

Как создать цикл, который будет запрашивать ввод переменной в течение (к примеру) 5 секунд при условии, что если я не ввёл переменную за это количество времени, то цикл завершает свою работу?

Я пытался сделать так:

```
int n;

chrono::steady_clock::time_point tend = chrono::steady_clock::now() + chrono::seconds(5);
While(chrono::steady_clock::now() < tend) {    
    cin >> n;     
    tend = chrono::steady_clock::now() + chrono::seconds(5);    
}
```

Возможно здесь глупая ошибка, работая с chrono час или два

Comment: я бы посоветовал оформить свой код так, чтобы его сразу можно было запустить, то есть, например, с инклюдами, мэйнем и while'ом с маленькой буквы, а то участники, как правило, народ ленивый, не хочет заниматься черновой работой, поэтому ваш вопрос будет долго оставаться без ответа только из-за того, что всем лень доводить ваш код (к тому, что еще надо еще отвечать по сути вопроса!)

Comment: Если кратко, то средствами чистых плюсов — ни как: нужны какие-то сторонние библиотеки или платформозависимые средства...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать multithreading (многоядерность). Т.е. одно ядро считает время, а другое ожидает ввод.